# Animated Scroll To The Top Link

Tags: jquery, html, css, blogs, blogger

How do I make a link in my blog, so that when someone clicks it, the link will scroll the webpage back to the top of the page? I've read tutorials online such as this, http://www.webtipblog.com/adding-scroll-top-button-website/, where most of these tutorials are showing you how to incorperate an image to scroll to the top.

If you scroll down to my blog, http://goneintranslation.blogpost.ca there's a link called "home" I want to make this link so that when users click it on it scrolls to the top. Does anyone know any articles or how to code this to make it happen?

Many thanks.

edit; I want to do something like this website, http://thechrisellefactor.com/, scroll to the bottom and it has a link saying "return to the top of the page."

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.scroll-top-wrapper').on('click', scrollToTop);
```

This is where the magic happens.
If you click the element with a class named "scroll-top-wrapper" it will issue the scrollToTop-function.

It doesn't matter if the element within this class is an image or a plain link.

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/xutLce4b/)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
        $('.top').addClass('show');
    } else {
        $('.top').removeClass('show');
    }
})
```

replace `.top` with your `class` or `id` on which it should scroll to top

```
$(".top").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to use jquery animate method to solve this...

**jQuery Code**

```
$("#scrollT").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6g4af5b5/